# How to suppress "Build Progress" bar when training an h2o model?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, h2o

I'm tuning my parameters by testing many models, and I'm fairly annoyed that I can't do much about the "Build Progress" bars that are cluttering up my iPython Notebook. I've skimmed the docs looking for some sort of "verbose" setting to turn off, but can't find it. Is there any way to turn this off when I want to train and evaluate dozens of models at once?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function you're looking for is called `h2o.no_progress()` and it shuts off all progress bars in your session.  If you search the Python module docs for ["progress"](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=progress#h2o.no_progress), you'll find it.