# Remove progress bar after completion of an h2o operation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, h2o

As a follow-up to [How to suppress "Build Progress" bar when training an h2o model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46937314/850781), I would like to *keep* the progress bar, but only while it is not 100% yet, after which I want it to disappear.

Note that clearing the output *completely* is **not** an answer: there may be valuable output there already that I want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to monitor the progress of your model, I would highly recommend using Flow in parallel with the api you are using (i.e. the R or Python API).

Specify a model ID to your model in say python, then open Flow, list all the models, then select your model and watch in build in real time.

That way you don't have to deal with a progress bar but you can still view the progress of your model **plus** you can stop your model and have it finish early using Flow.

If this is not your intention and you want the progress bar to disappear for some other reason, please make a [jira ticket](http://jira.h2o.ai) and detail this feature request since H2O-3 is open source and community input is really valued (so thanks!).